# Regex for city and street does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I would like to validate if the user entered valid city and street. In this case I use the `RegExp` that you can see below.

```
'^[a-zA-Z0-9 -]+,[^S\n]*[a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+(?:\n[a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+,[^S\n]*[a-zA-Z0-9 .-]+)*$'
```

The problem is that, it does not work as expected, because the user is allowed to enter `City,`  which may cause a lot of problems. I want to force the user to provide a value after the comma separator, instead of empty space which should not be allowed.

The values that should be correct are:

```
1. City-A, Street-B
2. City, Street
3. City, Street-A
4. City-A, Street,
5. City, ul. Street
6. City, ul.Street
...
```

Any hints, how the above regex could be replaced?

Comment: Will this work: [`^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -]*),[ \t]*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 .-]*)[.,\ \t]*$`](https://regex101.com/r/G2xSDz/1) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to use this regex to capture both values:

```bash
^([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -]*),[ \t]*([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 .-]*)[., \t]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2xSDz/3)

**RegEx Breakdown:**

- `^`: Start
- `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 -]*)`: 1st capture group to match city name that starts with a letter
- `,`: Match a comma
- `[ \t]*`: Match 0 or more space or tab
- `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9 .-]*)`: 2nd capture group to match street name that starts with a letter
- `[., \t]*`:Match 0 or more space or tab or dot or comma
- `$`: End